# Laravel Mix empties file while "watch"-ing

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

- Laravel 5.4.26
- NPM 5.4.2
- Node 8.1.2

I am running `npm run watch` and it works perfectly with all my SASS or CSS files. I also have this line of code there:

```
.scripts(['resources/assets/js/specific/dashboard.js'], 'public/js/specific/all.js')
```

Every time I run `npm run watch` *dashboard.js* is succesfully compiled into *all.js*.

However every time I make a change in *dashboard.js* laravel mix instantly empties `all.js` never to fill it up again. If I `Ctrl+c` the process and run `npm run watch` again it compiles it successfully again.

This is bad because every time I make a change in the js (that I'm currently developing) I need to go back and restart the process and wait for it.

Comment: make you should create an issue [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues)

Comment: If this really is an issue and not my mistake, it's a serious one... Basically Mix watch does not work for JS files. And it has been like that for almost 6 months. I hope it's my mistake.

Comment: Are u working on windows or *nix systems?

Comment: It's Linux, just discovered that if I have several files in the .scripts directive it empties only the one that I change and save while it's "watch"-ing.